# How to reset microcontroller after X amount of hours/seconds?

Tags: microcontroller, reset, watchdog

I know there are similar posts to this I am just looking to see if there are any new more efficient solutions. I have a MCU and I am looking to add a circuit in between the power supply and the MCU that can force a power-cycle after X seconds/hours.

Comment: Any more efficient solution would be a dedicated IC. You can Google "watchdog timer IC" to find examples. Specific recommendations are off topic thought.

Comment: Many microcontrollers include a "watchdog timer" that can be enabled by software.  The watchdog timer will cause a reset if not kicked occasionally.

Comment: What does the 555 solution cost you and can you then define what you mean by "cost effective." How inefficient is the 555 and what would you call "efficient," by comparison? Give us some numbers here.

Comment: @PeterBennett I can't use the software watchdog on the main MCU because I need a circuit/system independent of the main system

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the internal watchdog?

Comment: @Transistor (1) I don't know of any that accept only windowed kicks. (2) Many of them are tied to the MCU clock (should have their own separate clock.) (3) Many don't actually reset the MCU, but just issue an NMI of sorts. (4) Many are maskable in software and can be repurposed as a timer; external ones are always active. (5) They don't reset external hardware (which may be appropriate.) (6) External ones often support a much wider designable timing range. (7) External ones can support different timing for reset vs normal operation, instead of "disabled until ready to go" with internal ones.

Comment: Thanks, jonk. Some of those are new to me. You're obviously on the night-shift again. I hope all is going as well as possible.

Comment: @Transistor Being on night shift can be a good thing. I'm on a normal schedule and others are on their schedules, as well. (We have 24/7 & 365 coverage here! Doors never close.) May mean other business activities are on track and not driving me crazy.

Comment: @ThePhoton I believe the watchdog timer is a fast monitoring device. My system just needs a power-cycle every 24-48 hours consistently. Can these watchdogs do that or is there something simpler/cheaper to implement?

Comment: @SChand, originally you wrote that the alternative was a 555 timer. A 555 does not accurately measure over more than a few seconds, and 100 ms or so is the regime where it's more typically used. An off-the-shelf watchdog would work on roughly the same time scale. For resets every 24 hours, you'll probably want to use another micro.

Comment: @ThePhoton Is it uncommon for the 555 to measure 24 hours? I am ok if the 555 is a few seconds or minutes inaccurate. Another micro would add more cost than I would like to add vs a $0.40 555 chip

Comment: Does your 555 datasheet show any performance curves with output periods greater than 10's of seconds? To measure 24 hours with a 555, I'd run the 555 at maybe 1 Hz, and use counters to count up until 24 hours. You'd also need a circuit to generate a short pulse (maybe another 555) when the terminal count is reached. The micro you'd use instead would probably be no more than $2.

Comment: @ThePhoton I am using NE555P and I don't see any chart showing performance over time. The 555 would also need a signal to drive the trigger which I am assuming can be used from an oscillator?

Comment: @ThePhoton $2?  More like 35 cents for an ATTiny4, in quantity of 1.

Comment: @ThePhoton I see the ChrisStratton suggested a MCU that is cheaper but I am curious if I use a second MCU to control the current flowing to my main MCU via a transistor will the voltage/current be stable going into the main MCU?

Comment: @SChand, you don't use it to control current flowing to main MCU, you use it to drive the RESET input of the main MCU.

Comment: Do you trust your code vs a full scale production model watchdog timer from a major semiconductor company?

Comment: @Passerby, he wants a 24 hour delay on the reset. Is there an off-the-shelf watchdog with that much delay (I haven't looked)?

Comment: @SChand, on the 555, look at Fig 14 in the TI datasheet for NE555P. No recommondations for frequency lower than 0.1 Hz. You might get 0.01 Hz by extrapolation, but you can't count on it being accurate (due to leakage currents, etc) for that frequency or lower.

Comment: CMOS 555's (like LMC555) will go to longer delays. But only by a factor of 10 or so.

Comment: In that case, there are 555 like ICs intended for lower power and longer delays with better accuracy. A watchdog is there for if your code locks up, not for a periodic reset. Like the CSS555C has days as you can scale to 10^6

Comment: @Passerby I trust the code it's just I need this periodic reboot installed as I continue debugging what is causing the hangups (which seem to be solved by a power cycle). If I use the CSS555C to track days, is there something I can use to automatically pulse a trigger? I need this daily reboot to function on its own.

Comment: @Passerby that CSS555C chip is costly compared to buying my own MCU and using that to handshake with the main MCU and power cycling using a trasistor-switch if handshake fails... ideally I am seeking something not so costly

Comment: @ThePhoton I plan to control the current flowing to the main MCU because I am assuming the main MCU is no longer functioning so I can't send a signal to reset it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton what is better about ATTiny4 vs 8?

Comment: At this point, its no longer a high level question on what type of device does what you want, but a product recommendation. You have the name of the two types of chips that do what you want, and an option to roll your own MCU solution.

Comment: AFAIK there is no ATtiny8.  The ATtiny4 is smaller and cheaper than the ATTiny24/45/85, but also more limited and harder to work with.  It's basically targeted at replacing a single function that would be fiddly to implement with discretes and doesn't have an ideal fixed function IC solution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton my search corrected to ATtiny85, I didn't realize there is a ATtiny45 and ATtiny4

Comment: @SChand, if it's malfunctioning so hard that its hard reset input doesn't work, power cycling may not fix it either.

Comment: Your question is near to getting closed / put on hold because it's unclear/offtopic. Take your time and describe what your _actual underlying problem/challenge_ is. 24 hours timeout does not sound like usual malfunction detection for MCU programs. Why would a reset be necessary in the first place (e.g. error handling)? Be aware of the [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Asking to solve a problem X that should be solved like Y. Add the relevant details you already gave in the comment (I won't to cherry pick and edit them for you into your post).

Answer (score 4):

These are called watchdogs. They come as dedicated external ICs and have a variety of functions and features. Sometimes they also have low voltage monitoring.

Comment: ...and also on most MCUs as built in *internal* functionality.  Typically there's a brownout detector, too.

Comment: Can these ICs detect when a script on the main system has failed? I am not sure what the full scope of functionality is built into a watchdog IC

Comment: @SChand -- yes, you reset the watchdog timer in your main loop. If it doesn't update, then the watchdog will restart the MCU.

Comment: @WesleyLee I see how the SW watchdog is useful but I need a system independent of the MCU. I was thinking of using a 555 timer but not sure if that is my best option